# How to format this kind of code?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I came across a question that was weirdly formatted with ```` ``` ```` to indent code. As the output was unsexy, it tried to edit it with no luck, here's the question:

---

I have a Scala regex which does match with `pattern.findFirstMatchIn()` but not with a `match ... case` unpacking statement:

`val pattern = "\"(\\d+?)\",\"(.*?)\",(.+)$".r
          val line = "\"1795\",\"title\",\"desc     "
          println(pattern.findFirstMatchIn(line).isDefined)
          val pattern2Unpacking = line match {
            case pattern( category_id, title, description) =>
              true
            case _ => false
          }
          println(pattern2Unpacking)`

---

I'm familiar with the bullet list issue but I can't find information on this one, how to format it correctly and why does it occurs?

**Note**: Feel free to try to edit this post

Comment: I think you can just remove the backticks and indent to (at least) 4 spaces on each line, as long as it's not part of a bullet list, right? That's what I've been doing when I encounter this type of formatting error, anyway.

Comment: @MageXy It doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Someone is attempting to use GitHub flavored Markdown to format their code blocks, which is unsupported on Stack Exchange. See [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125148/implement-style-fenced-markdown-code-blocks). What results are a series of `<code>` elements and not a single `<pre>` in sight.

The problem with this specific code block is unrelated to that, though. There is a U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR after the `\"desc` portion of the code that's preventing the entire thing from being formatted as a code block even when you remove the ```` ``` ```` bits (which is probably why the author put them there in the first place). Removing that allows the code block to render correctly.

Here is the sanitized Markdown source, with the triple backticks and the control character removed (I don't know if the whitespace between `"\desc` and the last `"` should also be removed):

```
I have a Scala regex which does match with `pattern.findFirstMatchIn()` but not with a `match ... case` unpacking statement:

          val pattern = "\"(\\d+?)\",\"(.*?)\",(.+)$".r
          val line = "\"1795\",\"title\",\"desc        "
          println(pattern.findFirstMatchIn(line).isDefined)
          val pattern2Unpacking = line match {
            case pattern( category_id, title, description) =>
              true
            case _ => false
          }
          println(pattern2Unpacking)
```

Comment: Thanks for `U+2028` I didn't know about it.